# Connecting to any URL: java.io.IOException TCP Open

Tags: java, http, java-me

I have a midlet that reads some bytes from google to test, it runs ok on my nokia and sony ericsson cellphones but in "Samsung GT-E2120L cellphone it doesn't work, I get "java.io.IOException TCP Open" Exception when I try to get the connection response code

```
HttpConnection conn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open("http://www.google.com");
// The exception throws HERE
int rc = conn.getResponseCode();
byte[] buff = new byte[255];
conn.openInputStream().read(buff);
```

Note: I have credit :)

Note2: I can access to google from native navigator of the "Samsung cellphone"

Note3: I had tried to Connect to the URL with 3 diferent modes: Connector.READ,Connector.WRITE, Connector.READ_WRITE

Note4: My application is not trusted but I have the "javax.microedition.io.Connector.http" API Permissions

Note5: I know that the read buffer[255] is hard coded but it's only for test

Anyone can help me? 
Thanks in advance and thanks for reading

Comment: for your app, is there access for GPRS, in some phone like sony-ericsson i know there is different settings for default browser and java app, so i would like you to make sure that does your java app has access to internet using gprs?

Answer (score 0):

"java.io.IOException TCP Open" - is it all that you get from exception?

If you declared javax.microedition.io.Connector.http in MIDlet-Permissions try to delete it. Really you don't need this parameter if your midlet is unsigned.

Some samsung mobiles (D600, E200) have bug: after some time without any correlations with actions were did they became unavailable to use internet from midlets. May be it's your case?

And as commentator said it could be different settings for accessing internet from java.